# Any reasons to look at alternatives to inheritance / polymorphism?

Tags: c++, inheritance, collections, polymorphism, iteration

I often have the need to be able to iterate over a collection of objects that have similar, but not identical functionality (imagine a collection of `Task` objects that all have their own implementation of a `Do()` function, for instance).

I typically implement this by having a base `Task` class (with a virtual `Do()`) that all tasks derive from. I can then hold a collection of these in a `vector<Task*>` or a `vector<unique_ptr<Task>>`.

Are there any reasons (or, indeed, viable ways) to do this differently?

**Edit:**

I used (imaginary) `Task` objects purely as an example for simplicity's sake. In reality, a typical case from an actual, current project would be a UI composition framework. On each layout update pass, a "visual tree" is traversed from a root container and its child controls are arranged, recursively (child container controls have other controls as children etc), based on child properties like offset, alignment, size etc. Parents position their children differently according to their type and configuration (think WPF's Canvas, Grid, StackPanel etc).

The tree is constantly changing at run-time by way of visual elements being dragged and dropped between containers and other dynamic / user-instigated behavior, and the controls themselves are an ever expanding family (that supports new control types via plugins).

Comment: sounds as the right approach, unless you are worried about runtime performance due to virtual dispatch. in the latter case, you can probably use a template tag-base compile time dispatch.

Comment: unique_ptr<Task> is actually no RAII. A RAII implementation would be a Task handling it's uniqueness.

Comment: @DieterLücking `unique_ptr<Task>` is nothing more than a pointer to a Task-_derived_ object, but where (for all intents and purposes) the object is "stored in the vector" (i.e. you don't have to keep it somewhere else (persistantly) just to be able to put a pointer to it in the vector, as with `vector<Task*>`). `vector<Task>` isn't up to the job, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to be as generic as possible for just "a collection of tasks", you can use `std::function`:

```
std::vector<
    std::function<void()>
> tasks;
```

That way your tasks don't all have to inherit from `Task`. Or even be objects.

```
void printHello() { cout << "Hello\n"; }

tasks.push_back(printHello);
tasks.push_back([]{ /* do stuff */ });

struct Object // doesn't inherit from anything
{
    void operator()() const {
        // do other stuff
    }
};

tasks.push_back(Object{});
```

This technique is called "type erasure".

Comment: My example of `Task` objects with a simple `Do()` function was greatly simplified. I updated the question with an example closer to a real-life scenario.

Comment: @d7samurai If you're working with a collection of UI objects that you need to do stuff with then yeah, sounds like a pretty standard use-case for polymorphism. What don't you like about it?

Comment: I have nothing against it - it's just that lately I've heard programmers that I respect refer to polymorphism as a silly concept (in favor of "much more powerful" ways of doing things, like mixins etc), and I was wondering why that might be (and if there were alternatives to inheritance etc for my use cases)..

Comment: @d7samurai In C++, a mixin is polymorphism. It's not like in Ruby or other languages where it's a more separate concept. A mixin here would still be `class MyWidget : public FooMixin, public BarMixin, public TaskMixin { ... };` to be used in a `vector<TaskMixin*>`.

Comment: @d7samurai "I've heard programmers refer to poly. as a silly concept" .. You were probably speaking across different contexts. The context you put forth here is one where poly. is definitely not silly at all. But there are many other contexts in which using dyn-poly is very silly, and these are a very common anti-patterns in real-life code. So, it might be that those programmers were over-compensating a bit, venting some frustrations at these common anti-patterns, or you simply didn't understand the usage context they were discussing.

Answer (score 1):

> *"Are there any reasons do this differently?"*

Yes, there are:
Think twice, if you really need runtime polymorphism, it could be an unnecessary performance hit for particular situations.

You might get well off using static polymorphism, if all of your `Task` implementations are known at compile time. See the [CRT pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), how to implement static polymorphism.

---

> *"Could you elaborate on that?"*

Well, I'll try (As you're actually asking for a `virtual` interface needed because of the non compile time known *Plugin* interface):

You can have a (pure) `virtual` base interface implemented by some CRTP base class:

```
struct TaskInterface {
    virtual void Do() = 0;
    virtual ~TaskInterface() {}
};
```

---

Implementation can be provided with a CRTP:

```
template<class Impl>
class TaskBase 
: public TaskInterface {
    virtual void Do() {
        DoDerivedImpl();
    }
protected:
    void DoDerivedImpl() {
        static_cast<Impl*>(this)->DoImpl();
    }

    void DoImpl() {
         // Issue a static_assert error here, that there's no appropriate overridden
         // implementation of DoImpl() available:
         static_assert
            ( static_cast<Impl*> (this)->DoImpl != TaskBase<Impl>::DoImpl
            , "TaskBase requires an appropriate implementation of DoImpl()");
    }
};
```

---

```
class TaskType1 : public TaskBase<TaskType1> {
public:
    void DoImpl() {
        cout << "TaskType1::DoImpl()" << endl;
    }
};

class TaskType2 : public TaskBase<TaskType2> {
public:
    void DoImpl() {
        cout << "TaskType2::DoImpl()" << endl;
    }
};

class TaskType3 : public TaskBase<TaskType3> {
    // Missing DoImpl()
};
```

---

```
int main() {
    std::vector<TaskInterface*> tasks;
    TaskType1 t1;
    TaskType2 t2;
    // TaskType3 t3; // Uncomment to see compile time errors
    tasks.push_back(&t1);
    tasks.push_back(&t2);
    // tasks.push_back(&t2);

    for(std::vector<TaskInterface*>::iterator it = tasks.begin();
        it != tasks.end();
        ++it) {
            (*it)->Do();
    }
}
```

See [***LIVE DEMO***](http://ideone.com/60kqce) for regularly compiling implementation.
See [***LIVE DEMO***](http://ideone.com/3TZgb5) for uncommented usage of `TaskType3`.

---

The advantage is, you can easily use several mixin implementations for several interfaces, to setup your final *'Plugin'* classes.

Comment: @Barry That was intentional: `P` for _'pattern'_ is redundant!

Comment: Yeah but the term is "CRTP". It may be redundant to say CRTP pattern (like ATM machine), but CRT to me is Cathode Ray Tube. Perhaps just "See CRTP, how to implement..." ?

Comment: @Arkadiy Depends, CRTP doesn't generally mean you don't have vtables implemented.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Could you elaborate on that? How to get a CRTP `Task` class from a collection and call the `Do()` method without runtime polymorphism and the unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: I don't understand CRTP *with* virtuals. What does `class TaskType1 : public TaskBase<TaskType1>` give you that `class TaskType1 : public TaskInterface` doesn't?

Comment: @Barry There still might be enough logic code left to be implemented in `TaskBase`, that's independently of `TaskType1`.

Comment: [Here's](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/12/05/the-cost-of-dynamic-virtual-calls-vs-static-crtp-dispatch-in-c) an interesting article that benchmarks CRTP vs dynamic polymorphism.

I was surprised to see how much of a difference there was (CRTP appeared ~6x faster). That said, it's much more common to see dynamic polymorphism in practice, and I wouldn't prematurely optimize things unless you know beforehand that performance is certainly going to be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You've described something that is essentially a canonical use-case for dynamic polymorphism. It is often used as an example in OOP because it's very clear that dynamic polymorphism is very (most?) appropriate in this general case.

But there are certainly some reasons for using an alternative or a variation of it. Most of these reasons are "special cases".

One common variant is to use some form of wrapping of the dynamic polymorphism into a value-semantic classes. One variant in that family is using type-erasure (e.g., `std::function`). There are reasons why this is better because it can be more light-weight in some situations (e.g., state-less functor for the "Do()" function). Another reason for this is also that you might not want to tie your classes to a "Task" base-class, or you might have existing classes that you want to adapt to this purpose in a non-intrusive way (not changing their inheritance).

Another alternative is to not use virtual functions and inheritance at all. For example, if your set of "derived classes" is small and contain very similar classes (same data members), then you might get some performance benefits to being able to store those objects by value inside the vector (i.e., memory access patterns will be more direct and efficiently packed on cache memory). If there are only small variations in the implementation of the "Do()" function, it might be worth it to simply implement those different behaviours within one single class (e.g., with a switch-statement inside the Do function) that can be stored by value.

And, of course, if you don't need a run-time mechanism, then you shouldn't use dynamic polymorphism, but use static polymorphism instead.

But in general, I would say that the alternatives to dynamic polymorphism are more appropriate in other cases, not the "collection of different objects" scenario that you just put forth. For example, when you need polymorphic behaviour in algorithms (mixins, policies, visitors, etc.), then there are much more reasons to resorting to an alternative.

Comment: @DieterLücking The point was to give a serious and somewhat comprehensive answer to the question... I guess this is not something that is commonly found here on SO. I guess I should do like SO's resident coding kiddies do: shout out the few buzz-words that they know (e.g., RAII, type-erasure and CRTP), echo the same old talking points and then post the first few links that pop up on a google search. Would you prefer that? Or was this comment also TL;DR?